# How can I fix Autodiscover for local clients in on premise Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange

After following this guide:
https://acbrownit.com/2014/04/04/exchange-autodiscover-episode-2-attack-of-the-exchange-server/

My internal Outlook clients can't connect to Exchange 2013 server. 
I was trying to get rid of a certificate error because of the DOMAIN.local not being included in the certificate.

I only changed ServiceBindingInformation attribute from:

```
https://autodiscover.DOMAIN.local/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
```

to:

```
https://autodiscover.DOMAIN.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
```

Since then, I've reverted back hoping it would resolve the issue with the internal Outlook clients but nothing changed. OWA is having issues too. After logging in, the page, 'Something went wrong' comes up.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you create the appropriate DNS record in the correct DNS zone?

Comment: If I am reading that page correctly then you need to create the entire DNS zone, and then populate it with A records and an MX record. So you would need both DOMAIN.local and DOMAIN.com.

Comment: Yes, from the article: "Note, though, that like the SRV record you will be forcing your internal clients to go out of your network to the Internet to access your Exchange server. To keep this from happening, you will have to have an Internal version of your External DNS zone that has Internal IPs assigned in all the A records. There just is no way around that with private domain names any longer."  So if the SCP now says DOMAIN.com then DOMAIN.com must exist in your internal DNS.

Comment: I've reverted back in any case so there's no need for the extra DNS records. SCP is now pointing back to DOMAIN.local and I still can't get any clients connected to Exchange.

Comment: Hi,
The “servicebindinginformation” attribute is related to “AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri” value by “Get-ClientAccessServer”.
What is your configuration now?
Internal domain client will check the SCP first, get the URL, then try to connect.
I think you need a domain.com DNS zone, and Autodiscover.domain.com record points to the Exchange server if using “https://autodiscover.domain.com/...”.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with it. Also I used same guide. Finally i realized that I had a typo in ServiceBindingInformation attribute. Then it worked well. If you are using SCP (default setting of EX2013), you shouldn't set up any discover DNS record for it. 
The autodiscover configuration is pointing to AD SCP.

Ales.